# Why does encoding fails for some videos that I upload (laravel ffmpeg)

Tags: laravel, ffmpeg

I am using laravel ffmpeg and everything seems to be working but I am having one little issue. Laravel FFmpeg is not encoding some of the videos. When I try uploading a different one it says that the **Encoding Fails**. I am almost done with my project but this one issue is in my way. Can someone help me? Here is my code

```
       ` $vid = $request->file('vid');


        $filename = $vid->getClientOriginalName();
        $request->vid->move(public_path('/app'), $filename);
        $name_file=uniqid().'video.mp4';
     $ffp=FFMpeg::open($filename)
->addFilter(function ($filters) {
    $filters->resize(new \FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(640, 480));

})
->export()
->toDisk('local')
->inFormat(new \FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264('libmp3lame'))
->save($name_file);


$viddy->title=$name_file;
$viddy->save();`
```

Comment: If you try to upload the same video again, does it give you the same error?

Comment: @user3158900 no not all. I have one video called ee.mp4 which goes through fine, then I have another video called cree.mp4 and that's when I get encoding failed, and i am not sure why